# Changing the specific colors used in ggplot in R, when a condition is already determining colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just started with using R, and I'm trying to make a graph in ggplot.
I made an example data frame.

```
AGE <- c(50, 52, 50, 65, 81)
Label <- c("A","B","B","A","B")
Score <- c(8, 9, 5, 6, 10)
df <- data.frame(AGE,Label,Score)
```

When I graph it with ggplot the way I've been doing it, this is what I get, which is, in hindsight, not a great looking example dataframe.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=AGE,y=Score, color=Label)) +
geom_point(shape=1)
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyqDC.png)

So, the question is, if I want the A and B labelled dots to be, say, purple and green, how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=AGE,y=Score, color=Label)) +
geom_point(shape=1) + scale_color_manual(values=c("purple", "green"))
```